# Me in Micorosft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What does 'Me' represent in a statement like;

```
      var inboxMessages1 = await graphClient
        .Me
        .MailFolders.Inbox
        .Messages
        .Request()
        .OrderBy("")
        .GetAsync();
```

I can't see anything clear enough in the docs.

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1):

'Me' refers to the currently signed in user as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).